# Selenium Server error: Unable to get browser

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-9

I'm running Selenium Standalone Server 2.25 on Windows 7, with Internet Explorer 9 as a browser, and I'm getting this error for every test that requires opening the browser:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:
       Unable to get browser (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
       Command duration or timeout: 10 milliseconds
       Build info: version: '2.25.0', revision: '17482', time: '2012-07-18 21:08:56'
       System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_07'
       Driver info: driver.version: EventFiringWebDriver
       Session ID: 356e9fc8-2d2b-4808-964c-4a1fea7415f9 (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException)
```

What am I doing wrong? The exact same information appears on the Selenium Server console.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The error disappeared after enabling the Protected Mode settings for all the zones in Internet Explorer (Tools > Internet Options > Security tab).

Comment: Yup, oddly though, in the constructor of the IEDriver it does check for this, so it should have told you.

Comment: @Arran yes. I don't know why, but with the default IE configuration, it doesn't say what the problem is.

Comment: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver#required-configuration- explains why enabling protected mode for all zones will fix this IE bug (still present in IE11)

Comment: Helped me a lot

Answer (score 20):

**For IE 11 only**, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates.

For **32-bit** Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

For **64-bit** Windows installations, the key is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

Please note that the `FEATURE_BFCACHE` subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Important: Inside this key, create a `DWORD` value named `iexplore.exe` with the value of 0

Download the registry file from 
http://heliumhq.com/docs/internet_explorer.

See https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver for this and more necessary IE configuration steps.

Comment: Now this is strange. Until about 2 hours ago my tests were working without any issues on IE. Without any changes suddenly they stopped working, I got the same error message as OP. But this solution fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

My usual tactic is to individually add sites that require automated testing to 'trusted sites' in IE.

Go to Tools > Internet Options > Security then click Trusted Sites and the Sites button and individually add the website(s) needed.

Probably easier to get past your IT manager that way if you're locked down.

Comment: Use same solution for last version of IE 11 use 32 bit version of IEDriver (tested with selenium 2.47.1 and 2.50.1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Selenium at Eclipse and my solution for this trouble is run IDE as administrator

Answer (score 0):

i have added the url which i am trying to access in the Trusted Sites that way it worked for me after trying all the turnarounds

Answer (score -1):

You must try this...

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();

capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",IE_DRIVER_PATH);
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```