# How to set up reliable parallel browsers environment based on Selenium

Tags: c#, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, teamcity

I'm having some troubles with building reliable environment for our Selenium based UI tests. We have tried Selenium Grid + latest Firefox (+ 41.x), Latest Chrome as well but they are always some problems with hanging browser and failing tests because of that (or builds). SeleniumDriver is latest as well (nuget 2.49.0).

I can mention also some crazy things like even with all this we still can't make browsers go full screen if test are started from Team City job against Selenium grid:

```
firefoxDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
//Make Firefox fullscreen for TeamCity agent's runs
((IJavaScriptExecutor)firefoxDriver).ExecuteScript(
                            "window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height)");
firefoxDriver.Manage().Window.Position = new Point(0, 0);
firefoxDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
firefoxDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("body")).SendKeys(Keys.F11);
```

We also tried to run the test locally by installing team city agent on the virtual machine (we use Azure) - still same problem - maybe even worse...

Before each test we start new browser and after it we stop it with:

```
Driver.Close();
Driver.Dispose();
Driver.Quit();
```

but still they are some unstopped/hang browsers...

When executed locally from Visual Studio **1 by 1** (not as a suite) everything is OK.

Any suggestions what we might have done wrong?

Is it entirely browser fault? And if yes what we can use? I would like to try PhantomJS (Ghostdriver) but it's kind a outdated and have another set of problems with it. Any other option? IE 11 also have a problem -> [Selenium Server error: Unable to get browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694001/selenium-server-error-unable-to-get-browser) which did not quite work for us.

Not to mention some stuffs like 5 dropdowns can be automated but the 6th one is not working in Firefox, but works on Chrome and vice versa.

Also I have a feeling the Azure VM is really slow maybe real machine would help (keep in mind that even on my machine if I run it with team city commands browsers hangs as well).

I'm pretty sure someone else also face all this problems and hopefully have some guidance to share which I think would be helpful to others as well in the road to stable automation environment for Selenium UI tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to see the change Log under selenium official website, and use the browser and selenium which are compatible to each other. After that you can use the code for setup and login.